# Ember.js: Passing parameters to child view rendered with Handlebars {{view}} Helper

Tags: ember.js

I have this view `MessagesView` where I want to render `n` child views each of type `MessageView`.

The handlebars template section, for `MessagesView` looks like so:

```
{{#each message in controller}}
    {{#link-to "message" message class="list-group-item"}}
        {{view view.messageView}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

The view definitions are pretty straightforward, the only interesting bits are probably:

```
MessagesView = Ember.View.extend({
    messageView: MessageView,
    ...
});

MessageView = Ember.View.extend({
    messageId = 0;
});
```

I want to initialize `MessageView.messageId` to a particular value in the `{{#each}}` helper to `message.id`. Something like this hypothetical block of code:

```
{{view view.messageView({messageId: message.id})}}
```

I don't see any way to do that. Could someone point me to a scheme that would allow me to do that or perhaps outline any other standard practice to doing so?

**EDIT:**

---

I see a `viewName` property that can be passed to the child view through the `{{view}}` helper like so, [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_code-viewname-code-property):

```
{{#view viewName="aChildByName"}} hi {{/view}}
```

I guess I'm asking how to send other generic properties to the child view.

**EDIT 2**

---

Mostly for future visitors, this is mentioned in the discussion of [Components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by just adding it as an "attribute" when invoking the view.

```
{{#each message in controller}}
    {{#link-to "message" message class="list-group-item"}}
        {{view view.messageView messageId=message.id}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LordDaimos/he262/1/) for a sample.

Comment: Lol. Wasn't expecting this. I almost tried it blindly. Btw, is it mentioned anywhere in the docs?

Comment: I believe that it has been mentioned at least but I can't find it now.

Comment: Never mind. Found it here: http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/